# Add a blank column to Material UI Grid without using padding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I'm learning using Material UI Grid and I want to add a blank column (like padding from the right of the first element) on the right side of a column without using padding.

Consider the code :

```
import React from 'react';
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


const ExampleGridComponent = () => {

    const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
        root: {
            flexGrow: 1,
        },
        paper: {
            padding: theme.spacing(2),
            textAlign: 'center',
            color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
        },
    }));
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (

        <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>)
}

export default ExampleGridComponent;
```

It look like this : 
[image]

How can we put a blank column on the right of all the elements (brown color in the picture) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to:

- Document of [Material UI Grid](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/)
- Nested grid items: [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15195)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const App = () => {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1
    },
    paper: {
      padding: theme.spacing(2),
      textAlign: "center",
      color: theme.palette.text.secondary
    }
  }));
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={8}>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: Edit elastic-framework-0h4bj]

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your item grids with row and column.

```
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={9}>
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```